# Which Laptop for Lightroom, Photoshop CC 2015.5 and Premier Elements

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, laptop

I have spent months looking into a new laptop. It's primary use will be editing and developing photos in Lightroom but I will also be putting together photo and video slideshows in Premier Elements and maybe even premier pro in the near future. What I cant decide is what is more important; dedicated graphics card like the higher end Surface Book or more processing power like in the Dell Xps with Core i7 and 16GB of RAM. Can anyone give me a definitive answer. My budget is up to £1600 - I think.

Comment: The display is always the most important thing for editing photos. You can have the best graphics and processing power in the world, but if the display can't accurately display the colors from the GPU then you're not producing what you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

For Lightroom you need 8-16GB ram, the fastest CPU you can get and average or better GPU. If you don't use external monitor, get a laptop that has a good display.